# Python spearman correlation coefficient not matching.

Tags: python, statistics, correlation

So I have a data set which is molecular abundances as a function of a physical parameter, and I want to determine how correlated the two are to each other. Both of the parameters span several orders of magnitude.

Because the two are not linearly related, I chose to use the Spearman-rank correlation coefficient from `scipy.stats.spearmanr`. But my problem is that the results are sometimes making no sense, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Below is the figure, where the abundances are plotted for three different times (colors). But what is curious is that though the black line show a decline in abundance, and so a negative correlation coefficient, the two other lines show a positive correlation, though they are not that different from the black line!
[image: The example figure]

Here is the code I use, I excluded the cosmetic parts of the code.

```
for t in range(0, len(times)):
    ax.loglog(parameter, abunds[t], color=colors[t])
    corr_coeffs[t] = stats.spearmanr(np.log10(parameter),np.log10(abundances[t,:])
    patches.append(mpatches.Patch(color=colors[t], label="r=" + str(("%.2f"%corr_coeffs[t,0])) + ", p=" + str(("%.2f"%corr_coeffs[t,1])) + " | " + time_label[t]))
legend  =   plt.legend(handles=patches, fontsize="large", loc='best')
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

I would be extremely grateful if someone can explain to me this strange behaviour.